# Pro and cons calling finish

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-management

I want to know what are the pro and cons when you try to open a new activity with android and destroy the previous one straight away by calling finish.

People think that is a bad idea because Android can take care of the activity and drop them when there is too much memory used, but what about if I get inside that activity once and probably the user will never come back? Is this a bad option?

Also by finishing the activity, the history with the back button is "clear", so it wont get back to that activity ( only if your user flow needed to go back I think you should not call finish ).

And in terms of memory, is better to kill the activity with finish or leave android to have this activity in the background for *who knows for how long time*?

I feel like, that you kind of help the system to GC the activity that you closed  and make sure that the user wont need to tap the back button 100 times before getting out of the application.

**So what do you think? Better call Finish or not**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know what are the pro and cons when you try to open a new activity with android and destroy the previous one straight away by calling finish.

Either you want the user to return to the previous activity via the BACK button, or you do not.

- If you want the user to return to the previous activity via BACK, do not call `finish()`
- If you do not want the user to return to the previous activity via BACK, there are a multitude of options, depending upon where you *do* want the user to go when the user presses BACK

> People think that is a bad idea because Android can take care of the activity and drop them when there is too much memory used

No, [Android does not do this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html).

> is better to kill the activity with finish or leave android to have this activity in the background for who knows for how long time?

It is "better" to have the activity implement `onTrimMemory()` and reduce its memory footprint as needed. Do not harm the user expectations of the BACK button.

> that you kind of help the system to GC the activity that you closed and make sure that the user wont need to tap the back button 100 times before getting out of the application

Few users will "tap the back button 100 times". They will press HOME, or bring up the overview screen (a.k.a., recent-tasks list), or navigate to another app by other means.

Now, that being said, there *will* be times when you want to clear the task (back stack), again with an eye towards providing a logical flow for the user. For example, in an email app:

- The user launches the app, and a fresh task is created, with the user going to the app's launcher activity, which shows the messages in the user's inbox (A)
- The user taps on a "search" action bar item, bringing up a search activity, where they can search by various criteria (B)
- The user fills in search criteria and clicks the "Go!" button, which does the search and shows matching email messages (C)
- The user taps on an email message, bringing up an email-viewing activity (D)
- The user taps a "delete" action bar item, which should delete the message and return the user... somewhere

If you believe that the user should return to the search results (C), you could call `finish()` in D. If, however, you believe that the user should return to the inbox (A), you would call `startActivity()` on A with appropriate flags (e.g., `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`), to clear out the back stack and return the user to A.

In sum: do **NOT** call `finish()` to deal with heap space; implement `onTrimMemory()` instead. However, if **navigation** calls for `finish()`, then use it.

Comment: This a great explanation, will  `finish()` clear any reference in the memory or they will stay around until I start a new activity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` ? What about all the images loaded into a imageview? How do they get unloaded and free? Should they do be done manual on `onDestory` or `onTrimMemory` will do it form me?

Comment: @max246: "will finish() clear any reference in the memory" -- it should allow the activity to eventually be garbage-collected. "Should they do be done manual on onDestory or onTrimMemory will do it form me?" -- neither. Widgets should be garbage-collected after their activity is. If you wish to do stuff proactively, you do that yourself in `onTrimMemory()`.